# Filter Bound DataGridView by Unbound Column

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, filtering, databound

I have a `DataGridView` bounded to a `DataTable` from a DataSet.xsd. I added by code one additional column called `_RowString` to the `DataGridView`. It contains a string composed by all the string values contained into the other columns of the `DataTable` and I want to use that column to filter the `DataGridView`.

My first approach was based on adding the `_RowString` column directly to my `DataTable` and not to the `DataGridView`. But this caused some problems when I needed to insert or update a record, because adding and calculating the column on the `DataTable` **caused the** `RowState` **value of all the** `DataTable` **rows to be** `Changed` **and so the** `TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(DataSet)` **method was always updating all the records!**

I know that I can use a `BindingSource` to filter the `DataGridView` like I was doing before:

```
BindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[_RowString] LIKE '%{0}%'", FilterTextBox.Text);
```

But for the reason explained above, I don't want to add the `_RowsString` column to my `DataTable` object.

How can I filter the `DataGridView` using the `_RowString` unbound column without using a `BindingSource` and/or adding the `_RowString` column to my `DataTable` object?

Otherwise, is there a way to add a column to my `DataTable` **without** changing the `RowState` value?

Comment: Can you create the filter column as a 'computed column' by selecting the joined strings into one column, which you don't show in the datagridview?

Comment: @TaW Do you mean if I can create the _RowString column in the SELECT command associated to the DataTable in the DataSet?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. As it isn't a real column it can't get updated but I don't know what, if anything, needs to be done to keep the select updatable,

Comment: I also need to keep the _RowString column updated because the DataGridView is editable. So I need to refresh it by calling the Fill method of the TableAdapter, each time I INSERT or UPDATE a record. I'll try it next monday! :-)

Comment: @TaW It works without problems! Please post your solution so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach may well be to **include** a dummy filter column in the **select**.

If you add a 'computed column' to your `SQL`, using `Concat` to put all necessary columns, in the right order, into one additional column you will get it right in your result set.

Example:

```
select *, concat(last_name, ',', first_name) as filterColumn from persons;
```

As a computed column it will not be updatable and you will have to take care that the correct `Update` statement gets created, if you need to update the table.

You can make the `DataGridView` column invisible or maybe even delete it..